# Android Studio build gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I want to replace a string token(version) in a html file from assets folder.
My question is how I can accomplish this task with build gradle?

Thank you.

Comment: I did not really understant your question. You want to replace this token in your assert file at build time ? or just once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in build.gradle and works

```
    applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
        variant.mergeResources.doFirst{
            def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER

            if (null != buildNumber) {
                File valuesFile = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}/about.html")

                String content = valuesFile.getText('UTF-8')
                content = content.replaceAll('@VERSION@', buildNumber)
                valuesFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

THe first thing you need is to know how to replace your token with the desired value with command line (with `sed` or anything else you like).

Then you can add task in your gradle build logic :

```
task replaceToken {
    commandline "your command line"
}
```

Then you add dependance on this task :

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.depensOn replaceToken
}
```

In this scenario, after each build your asset file will have the version name in it. So your command line should be able to insert the token value even if there is already a value (you will have to use regexp to replace `<balise>whatever</balise>` by `<balise>token value</balise>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.